# How does current increase in an LR circuit in order to reach a steady-state?

Tags: electromagnetism

The equation of voltage of an LR circuit is given by:

$$\boldsymbol{\varepsilon_0} - L\frac{dI}{dt}= RI\;.$$

Now, before the circuit is closed, $i= 0\;$

As is written in books, the current then increases to a steady-value $\dfrac{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon_0}}{R}.$

But how does it increase?

The emf $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon_0}$ is always constant. Then how can the current increase?

Comment: Because the initial infinitesimal electric current in the L part of the circuit generates a magnetic flux when the switch is flipped.  The magnetic flux affects the current and so on until a balance is achieved.

Answer (score 1):

The EMF isn't actually constant. For $t>0$ the EMF is a constant value $\varepsilon_0$, but for $t<0$, the EMF is 0. So the EMF is best described by a step function. When you solve the differential equation to determine the response of the circuit, you can essentially ignore anything that happens at $t<0$ as long as you know the current at $t=0$. In this sense, the EMF is described as constant because only the behaviour at $t>0$ is relevant to determining the response.

It's not too difficult to solve the differential equation to find the exact solution.

$$L \frac{dI}{dt}+RI=\varepsilon_0$$

Plug in a test answer:

$$I = A+Be^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}$$

$$-\frac{LB}{\tau}e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}+RA+RBe^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}= \varepsilon_0$$

For the expression to be true at all times, the coefficients on the exponentials must be equal, while the constants must be equal as well.

$$A=\frac{\varepsilon_0}{R}$$

This is the steady state response you identified.

$$\tau = \frac{R}{L}\;.$$

This is the characteristic response time of the circuit.

To satisfy $I=0$ at $t=0$, we set $B=-A=-\frac{\varepsilon_0}{R}$

So the current is:

$$I = \frac{\varepsilon_0}{R}\left(1-e^{-\frac{L}{R}t}\right)$$

This produces the following curve:

[image: RL circuit graph]

Comment: @user36790 I'll have a look at it tomorrow